# Remove dashes surrounded by numbers on both sides

Tags: regex, textwrangler

I'm trying to search and replace using regex in TextWrangler (https://gist.github.com/ccstone/5385334, http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/textwranglerpower.html)

I have rows like this

```
56-84   29  STRINGOFLETTERS -2.54
```

I´d like to replace the dash in "56-84" with a tab, so I get

```
56    84    29  STRINGOFLETTERS -2.54
```

But without replacing the dash in "-2.54"

How do I specifically only remove dashes surrounded by numbers on both sides?
My regex knowledge is extremelly small, I tried to find `[0-9]-[0-9]` and replace with `[0-9][0-9]` but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link says "*The PCRE engine (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) is what BBEdit and TextWrangler use*". So hopefully you can use lookaround with your regex.

replace regex:

```
(?<=\d)-(?=\d)
```

replace with tab(`\t`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Worked nice

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to capture the numbers you want. So the regex would be:

```
^([0-9])-([0-9])
```

I'm assuming here that the numbers start at the beginning of the line. If not, you can remove the `^`.

Based on your link, the flavor of regex is PCRE, so backreferences look like `\1`, and `\2` in the replacement pattern. So your replacement pattern simply becomes:

```
\1\t\2
```

Here `\1` refers to the first group (so the first number) and `\2` refers to the second group (so the second number).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ^([0-9])-([0-9]) worked for me without the /. Too bad I cant upvote more than one answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's plain text, not sure you need TextWrangler.  You can just use the "sed" command of unix:

```
$ sed 's/\d-\d/\d\d/g' a.txt > b.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I already use TextWrangler to process the file in other ways, and I wanted to use only one program for everything.